# how do you tell if arcgis request is processed correctly?

Tags: python, arcgis-server

my company has an arcgis server, and i've been trying to geocode some address using the python requests packages.

However, as long as the input format is correct, the reponse.status_code is always"200", meaning everything is OK, even if the server didn't process the request properly.

( for example, if the batch size limit is 1000 records, and I sent an json input with 2000 records, it would still return status_code 200, but half of the records will get ignored. )

just wondering if there is a way for me to know if the server process the request properly or not?

Answer (score 1):

A great spot to check is the server logs to start with. They are located in your ArcGIS server manager (https://gisserver.domain.com:6443/arcgis/manager). I would assume it would log some type of warning/info there if records were ignored, but it is not technically an error so there would be no error messages would be returned anywhere.

I doubt you'd want to do this but if you want to up your limit you can follow this technical article on how to do thathttps://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012383

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I would look into the server manager and see if it shows anything.

Comment: I came across a better way to determine if the max record count has been hit. Take a look at the "exceededTransferLimit" limit property. That should be exactly what you need. 

https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/api-reference/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureLayer~ExceededTransferLimit.html

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-map-service-layer-.htm